# How to change the Field Group Horizontal Tab ID names

Tags: 7, entities

I've searched google for an answer to this question but can't seem to find anything.

I have the [Field Group](https://drupal.org/project/field_group) module installed, and I am using horizontal tabs.

The URL for each tab displays as.... example.com/business1#node_business_full_group_display_gallery

Whereas I would like it to display as....
example.com/business1#gallery

Looking at the original URL, it is printing the $entity_type, followed by $bundle, then $field_name. Whereas I would like it to just print the $field_name, or even better, the title of the tab.

I am looking in field_group.features.inc as it seems to be where I might be able to change how it displays the name, but I'm a little lost as to which bits to change.

You can view the file [here](http://drupalcode.org/project/field_group.git/blob/509572cbd80084845c3687edd0e283f735558ff8:/field_group.features.inc).

Comment: Please post answers as an answers, not edit them into question. You can answer your own question :)

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I tried to, but it says I couldn't answer it for another 7 hours because my reputation isn't high enough.

Comment: So post it tomorrow :) I bet it can live in a txt file on your hdd for few hours.